# Why static random access memory (SRAM) does not require a memory controller?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot

I have been studying the bootloaders, and there is an explanation on most of the sources that ROM code is on most of the chips that tell the chip where to go after it power up, and then ROM code load a small chunk of code into the SRAM.

My question is that DRAM requires a controller to run, but why SRAM doesn't? Who controls the SRAM? or how it is being controlled?
Also what happens after the system is being done with the SRAM and things are running off of DRAM?

I do not know yet if it makes sense or not but it would be best if you can answer from the perspective of u-boot and Linux.

Comment: Wouldn't this question be a better fit for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Codo No, this is more about the software and general theory than a hardware-based question.

Comment: No, it really is _not_ a software question, it is entirely about how the hardware works.  That is clear from both the wording of the question and the current answers.  It is clearly off topic - even if it is interesting.  SRAM is _static_ so requires no refresh control.  It has a simpler interface an timing; set the address bus, clock the output enable, read the data bus.  I don't see why uboot or Linux are relevant.  An SRAM large enough to run Linux would be prohibitively expensive and rather slow.  SDRAM is high density, inexpensive, and fast.

Answer (score 2):

> ... then ROM code load a small chunk of code into the SRAM.

That is a common procedure with some SoCs, but it's not required.  There are alternate boot schemes.

Etrax SoCs that used CRIS processors (which are now out of production) required the DRAM parameters to be stored in nonvolatile memory (NVM). The embedded ROM boot code accessed this NVM, and initialized the DRAM controller. The ROM boot code was thus capable of directly booting a Linux kernel.

Some ARM SoCs have a Boot Memory Selector (BMS) pin (e.g. Atmel AT91SAM9xxx and Microchip SAMA5Dx) that can disable the internal ROM code, and has the processor execute code after a reset from an *external* NVM (e.g. NOR flash) which has execute-in-place (XIP) capability.  Such a boot scheme could be customized to initialize the external DRAM, and then load U-Boot or even a Linux kernel.

---

> My question is that DRAM requires a controller to run, but why SRAM doesn't?
> Who controls the SRAM? or how it is being controlled?

DRAM requires a controller because this type of memory technology requires periodic refreshing.  The DRAM controller needs to be programmatically initialized before the DRAM can be accessed.  One of the functions of the boot code that is loaded into SRAM is to perform this initialization of the DRAM controller.

Interfacing SRAM by comparison is far more straightforward.  Normally there is no "SRAM controller".  The control logic to interface SRAM typically does reach the level of complexity to require a "controller".  For instance I've used a SBC that had its Z80 microprocessor directly connected to the SRAM (HM6264) and EPROM (MBM2764) memory ICs plus some logic for address decoding.

The "SRAM controller" found on a modern SoC is primarily a buffered interface for *external* SRAM with the internal system bus.  The internal SRAM of the SoC does not require any software initialization, and would be accessible immediately after a reset.

> Also what happens after the system is being done with the SRAM and things are running off of DRAM?

Typically the internal SRAM is left unused when it is not included as part of the memory that the Linux kernel manages.  I don't know if that is due to any technical reasons such as virtual memory or caching issues, or oversight, or desire for the simplicity of homogeneous memory.
For some SoCs the amount of internal SRAM is so small (e.g. 8 KB in Atmel AT91SAM926x) that the effort to utilize it in the kernel could be deemed to have a poor cost-to-benefit trade-off.
See this discussion regarding a [kernel patch](https://groups.google.com/g/linux.kernel/c/AofaWn5v1Sw) for SRAM on an Atmel/Microchip SAMA5D3x

A device driver could still utilize the internal SRAM as its private memory region for high-speed buffers.  For instance there was a [kernel patch](https://linux-arm-kernel.infradead.narkive.com/H6OFemPW/patch-re-submission-sram-tx-buffers-implementation-from-atmel-to-fix-tx-underrun-errors) to use the SRAM to hold Ethernet transmit packets to avoid transmit underrun errors.

Answer (score 1):

Both need controllers, DRAM however needs to be refreshed periodically to keep its state (in condensators), unlike SRAM that stores its states through latch circuits.
That means that if you want to keep the content of the memory after a reset (from Linux or U-Boot for example), you must have configured the DRAM controller to "auto refresh" the memory during the reset step. There is no such need with SRAM.

Comment: Then how is it accessible by the boot ROM in the start and DRAM isn't?

Comment: DRAM requires a more complex config, triggered by the software. Internal SRAM, could be initialized transparently.

Comment: How would such an SRAM controller look like, would you mind to add a link? I have a deep background in small microcontrollers and old processors, and their SRAMs never needed any controller.

Comment: @thebusybee, Static RAM "controller" is as simple as address decoder. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_decoder

Comment: @0andriy Well, I would not call an address decoder a memory controller.

Comment: @thebusybee the word was in double quotes on purpose.

Comment: @0andriy Hm, on a site where among others beginners seek knowledge, we should not confuse them with such "facts". I know several designs that don't even need an address decoder, nor for example a data bus driver between processor and memory that one could call "controller" with similar reasoning. -- However, the question was asked to Eric who claims that a SRAM needs a controller, without double quotes. Before myself claiming that it is plain wrong, I like to fill my potential knowledge gap.

Comment: Why does static RAM require a controller? If it does, then what electronic components wouldn’t?

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you are referring to SRAM from bootloader perspective, it is internal RAM which is accessible by the controller. This RAM is accessed by the controller using an AHB/AXI  bus (for ARM based devices). There might be a memory bridge which converts the signals from AHB/AXI bus to memory bus. So speaking from a software point of view, it is transparent, no specific software configuration is required to access this RAM.